# Do disabled Drupal modules affect performance?

Tags: performance, drupal, drupal-modules

Does having Drupal modules installed but not enabled have any effect on the performance of a Drupal site?

To put it another way.. Would removing disabled modules from a Drupal site have a positive affect on performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, there's no effect on performance from disabled modules.

The only exception is when Drupal checks for updates or builds the list of available modules. These will only ever affect the occasional cron and the administration pages that display all the available modules.

Answer (score 0):

They do affect performance. See this issue: http://drupal.org/node/329012

Answer (score 0):

Disabled modules do not affect the performance of Drupal Site. But there's no point of keeping modules that you think are not going to be useful. So yeah, better to clean some drawers.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).